# ExtJS stores - load JSON only once

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have multiple stores requiring the same JSON file with different rootProperty. Is there a possibility to load the json file once and populate all stores with it? As of now, three stores with three different rootProperties result in three calls to the server for a possibly megabyte-sized JSON file which contains the data and is generated over and over for every request.

The json looks like:

```
{"users":[{"id":0,"name":"John Doe",...},...],
 "threads":[{"id":0,"startedBy":0,"lastPost":0,...},...],
 "posts":[...]}
```

The three stores are all very similar, one example:

```
store: {
    model: 'Forum.model.Post',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax'
        url: '../api/json.php'
        reader: {
            type:'json'
            rootProperty:'posts'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a manual Ajax request and then populate each store with the appropriate bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could configure your stores with a memory proxy:

```
store: {
    model: 'Forum.model.Post',
    proxy:{
        type: 'memory'
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
            root: 'posts'
        }
    }
}
```

Then fetch the data once with an [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request) and load it into each store using the proxy:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '../api/json.php',
    success: function(response) {
        var result = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

        store.getProxy().data = result;
        store.load();
        // same procedure for the other stores...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

(Basically what Evan said) Set "autoLoad: false" on your stores.  In a controller, do a manual Ext.Ajax.request to get your large JSON object.  For each store, manually invoke store.loadRawData() and pass that JSON object as the first argument.

This approach has an advantage over just using a memory proxy: each of your stores will continue to communicate with the server via their proxies once you've loaded them up with data.

Comment: So if I loadRawData, it is clean? Or is it setDirty, so everything is posted back to the server if I do a sync?

Comment: I don't explicitly know, but based on having done something similar in the past I'd expect it to be clean.  You're just loading the data differently, but it's still going through your configured proxies.

Comment: I just tested and it goes in clean when using loadRawData. Thx. Have to yet decide which answer to mark as accepted... :D

Comment: Well i'd hope you'll be choosing which to accept soon!